# how to create ibm-web-bnd.xmi file for websphere 7

Tags: java, websphere-7

while trying to create the  ibm-web-bnd.xmi and ibm-web-ext.xmi files, 
what should be the value for the attribute "xmi:id" present in  tag.
Is there any guidelines for creating this or it can be any random number.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The xmi:id has no meaning to my knowledge.  In theory, it would be used if there were another layer of extension files (e.g., an ibm-web-bnd-2.xmi that extends ibm-web-bnd.xmi), which could in theory have `href="WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi#The_XMI_Id"` in order to refer to the element in ibm-web-bnd.xmi with that `xmi:id`.